# Mapbox SDK 10 java, add markers from geojson

Tags: java, mapbox

Most of the samples in SDK 10 lead to Kotlin, unfortunately there are no samples in Java. I'm trying to add markers from a local geojson file to an existing style.
This is what the beginning of my code looks like:

```
mapBoxView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri("mapbox://styles/account/clpnxwmpn00yfxwmqe1", new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {


            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

                StyleContract.StyleSourceExtension source = new StyleContract.StyleSourceExtension() {
                    @Override
                    public void bindTo(@NonNull StyleInterface styleInterface) {

                    }
                };

                GeoJsonSource jsonSource = new GeoJsonSource.Builder("markers-source").build();
                SourceUtils.addSource(style, source);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to add markers from a local geojson file to an existing mapbox  style.